# The Java JAR file <fileName> could not be launched - Mac OS

Tags: mac, windows, error, java

I developed a Java program in a PC running on Windows 10 and sent it to my professor, who owns a PC running on Mac OS.

In my computer, the executable runs perfectly, but on theirs it pops this message.

The Java JAR file  could not be launched. Check the console for possible errors.

Is there something wrong with my application or could be an error in their computer?

I used NetBeans to export the application to a .jar file, and selected the correct main class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of java does the professor have? What version do you have? Does your jar depend on others?

Comment: Hey @alexm https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295959/the-java-jar-file-could-not-be-launched?rq=1 Run the file in terminal to see more info

Comment: @user151019 I have the latest version of java, and my jar does not depend on other users. It does depend on some text files, that I sent to the professor along with the .jar file

Comment: There are several latest versions. Please provide the version numbers for both you a nd our professor