# The Java JAR file "Test.jar" could not be launched

Tags: macos, catalina, error, java

When I try to launch **Test.jar** apple pops up with the error **The Java JAR file "Test.jar" could not be launched.** when I do **java -version** it says...

```
java version "15" 2020-09-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have seen other questions and posts but none seem to answer the question.
I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.7

The file I am trying to run is https://cdn.cosmicclient.com/download/Launcher.jar

I would appreciate some help to play Minecraft. Any ideas?

Edit:

> Where does Test.jar come from?

**Test.jar** was a variable that I previously used to rename the .jar for simplicity purposes however it is the same exact file as **Launcher.jar**

> Can you show us the documentation or description of the jar.

https://cosmicclient.com is the source of the .jar thank you I should have put that into my first message. IF you are wondering if there is a virus, I have downloaded this on 2 different computers, 1 windows, 1 mac and then run an anti-virus software that didn't detect anything and the computer still run as they did. If you would like more evidence the virus-total scan (virustotal.com) is https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/c82150f000b7a9042f54756312b802494f149a57f75fd11247a7e823f915cb70/detection.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you could add a screen image of your specific error or link to what specific posts (and why they don’t work) that often helps us help you. (Or just edit and delete the I fail at documenting how I google for help part) we can assume that anyone that doesn’t clearly document what they tried is perfectly fine. Not all questions need to read like a court case with citations...  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295959/the-java-jar-file-could-not-be-launched (but a clear error message  is critical to edit in)

Comment: can you show us the documentation or discription of the jar. Just a link to a jar is not a good idea as that is how viruses can spread. Where does Test.jar come from? It is not the file you give the link to

Comment: Perhaps renaming it is the problem

Comment: I've tested this on two different machines and it works fine.  Are you using the command `java -jar Launcher.jar`?   Note, if you rename the file to `Test.jar` it will download a new `Launcher.jar` file.  You need to keep the original name.

Comment: @Allan thanks for your response however after making the post I tried that and it also didn't work. It is weird because I am able to run other Java programs. Also tried on a different mac and I am able to download it.

Comment: Try downgrading to Java 14

Comment: Not a bad idea ill try it tomorrow!

Comment: @Allan I think i figured out the problem I just need a workaround. The computer I am trying to install it on I have no admin rights, so I am using the trick here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyVLV6CutVY] that works with other jar files aswell just not this one. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see what admin rights have to do with it.  I downloaded the file, and via command prompt issued the command.  Never once did it  ask for admin credentials.